# How to parse this JSON in to string in android?

Tags: android, json

Can someone show me how to write this json into a code?

Is it correct if I get this json data as json object first and the loop the jsonarray in the try catch block in android?

```
{"charges":[{"Fhour":"0.3","Shour":"0.2","Rhours":"0.1"}]}
```

Kindly help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your String can be parsed like

```
String json = "{\"charges\":[{\"Fhour\":\"0.3\",\"Shour\":\"0.2\",\"Rhours\":\"0.1\"}]}";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray charges = jsonObject.getJSONArray("charges");
        for (int i = 0; i < charges.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = charges.get(i);
            String fHour = c.getString("Fhour");
            String sHour = c.getString("Shour");
            String rHours = c.getString("Rhours");
            Log.d("(f,s,r)Hours : ", "(" + fHour + "," + sHour + "," + rHours + ")");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use built-in JSON library.

```
JSONObject buddiesDoc = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray buddies = buddiesDoc.getJSONArray("buddies");

for (int n = 0; n < buddies.length(); n++) {
    JSONObject object = buddies.getJSONObject(n);
    object.getString(BuddyManager.CACHED_BUDDY_KEY_CONTACTID);

...
```